# Add value to input by click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field, by click value become * when I lose my focus field become clean. How to add additional * to input by every single click?

```
$('body').append("<input type='text' />");

$('input').click(function() {
  $(this).val('*');
});

$('input').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).val(''); 
});
```

Comment: I would suggest you add sample desired output to your question for clarity.

Comment: If input clicked 3 times. I'll see '***' in the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are replacing the value of the input field.  You want to append to it.  Change `$(this).val('*');` to `$(this).val($(this).val() + '*'));`

Answer (score 0):

Your `mouseleave()` function call is what's making the field blank. If for every click you want to add an asterisk:

```
$('input').click(function() { 
  $(this).val('*' + $(this).val()); 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable outside the functions to store the `*`

```
$('body').append("<input type='text' />"); 

var inputVal="";

$('input').click(function() { 
    inputVal +="*";
    $(this).val(inputVal); 
}) 

$('input').mouseleave(function() { 
    $(this).val(''); 
})
```

Comment: You can just do `this.value += "*"`

Comment: Yes... But OP clears the value on mouseleave... So got to store it somewhere.

Comment: *«How to add additional * to input by every single click?»* Is clear to me. Even if I don't see any real use to it... ;)

Comment: but only add additional * while the user have the mouse over the input field? When mouse leaves it should be cleared and be like if it was from the beginning

Comment: Looking at the question, it looks like what he wants... And it's what it does. The question is clear... The use is questionnable... But only OP can comment it ;)